# Show grouped rows in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

How can I group an  number of rows into a set columns based on the grouping criteria?

For example,

```
ID       Type            Total     
==============================
36197   Deduction         -9
36200   Deduction         -1
36337   Deduction          1
36363   Deduction          0
36364   Deduction          0
36200   Safety            -1
36342   Safety             0
36350   Safety            10
36363   Safety             0
36364   Safety             1
```

Into

```
ID      Deduction       Safety
==========================================
36197    -9              0
36200    -1             -1
36337     1              0
36363     0              0
36364     0              1
36342     0              0
36350     0              10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use case statements to conditionally aggregate:

```
select      id,
            sum(case when type = 'Deduction' then total else 0 end) as deduction,
            sum(case when type = 'Safety' then total else 0 end) as safety
from        tbl
group by    id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, (SELECT TOTAL FROM TABLE AS A WHERE A.ID = X.ID AND A.TYPE = 'DEDUCTION') AS DEDUCTION,(SELECT TOTAL FROM TABLE AS B WHERE B.ID = X.ID AND B.TYPE = 'SAFETY') AS SAFETY
FROM TABLE AS X;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve by using pivot.

```
select * from tableA
pivot (
max(total) for type in (Deduction,  Safety) 
) as pvt
```